# Can't get vscode new unity extension to work (Fixed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am facing an issue in Unity 2022.3.15f1 where I am not getting any errors, syntax highlighting, or auto-complete features in Visual Studio Code. I have tried several troubleshooting steps, but none have resolved the issue. Here's a list of what I've attempted:

- Installed Visual Studio Editor from the package manager (v2.0.22).
- Installed Visual Studio Code Editor from the package manager (v1.2.5).
- Removed each extension and used them exclusively.
- Downgraded Visual Studio Editor Extension to v2.0.20.
- Reset my Visual Studio Code settings.
- Regenerated project files.
- Tested on a new blank project.
- Reinstalled .NET SDK Framework and Mono, ensuring the path is valid and accessible via the terminal.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to identify the root cause of the problem. I had similar issues in the past, but the current situation perplexes me as there are no error messages or indications of a broken configuration.

It may sound like the regular common problem of the autocomplete not working, please note that this problem is different as the common troubleshooting steps did not resolve the problem.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on additional troubleshooting steps, I would greatly appreciate your insights. This issue is causing significant frustration, and any help in resolving it would be invaluable.

Comment: you werent overly specific in "visual studio code editor extension" where is that one from?

Comment: @BugFinder You are 100% right, i edited the question and fixed it.
I was referring to the extension in the "Unity Package Manager"

Comment: OK, so unity have given up on vs code..  As code itself points you to, you need to use the microsoft way, and follow it exactly.  If you follow it exactly it will work, if you dont. it wont.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it!
The solution was very simple but i don't understand why works.

The solution is just to delete the "/usr/local/bin/dotnet" shortcut.
This makes all parts of the C# Dev Kit use the same dotnet (in my case "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet")